# How to set initial value as 'Hidden'

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm [following this example](https://jsfiddle.net/3hdt03wf/) to create a piece of text, which when clicked, expands / collapses text.

How do I set the initial value to be hidden, so that initially the paragraph is collapsed, and when clicked will expand?

Below is the code.

```css
div#expand {
  width: 500px 
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script>
    function show() {
      if (document.getElementById('expand').style.display == 'none')
        document.getElementById('expand').style.display = 'block';
      else
        document.getElementById('expand').style.display = 'none';
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick=show()>About Us</a>
    <div id="expand">
      <p>this is all about us. <br></p>
    </div>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/3hdt03wf/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById('expand').style` will check the inline written styles not from your css file...So try to write inline css `display:none;` to that element.

Also you can't code a `<p>` tag inside another `<p>` tag...its invalid.

Also you have missed `;` after `width:500px` in your css

```js
function show() {
  if (document.getElementById('expand').style.display == 'none')
    document.getElementById('expand').style.display = 'block';
  else
    document.getElementById('expand').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
div#expand {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick=show()>About Us</a>
<div id="expand" style="display:none;">
  <p>this is all about us.<br></p>
</div>
```